# 'Prioritize' one column over another

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with subscription table currently and I'm creating a cron job that will take records based on some condition from the subscription table.

I want to select all subscription records that have either been `renewed_at` or `created_at` (these are column names) on certain date, seems easy so I do it like this, if the date is `2013-10-16` :

```
select * from subscription where
(subscription.renewed_at between '2013-10-16 00:00:00.000000'
and '2013-10-16 23:59:59.999999') OR 
(subscription.created_at between 2013-10-16 00:00:00.000000' 
and '2013-10-16 23:59:59.999999')
```

So here is what I want to be sure, and I'm not sure how to do it.

I want to *prioritize* `renewed_at` column over `created_at` column, in a sense that if somebody renewed their subscription at a certain date that I should select the record based on that date rather than on `created_at` date. In case however the `renewed_at` is not there I should select the record based on the `created_at` date.

And I should not select the record based on created_at if the `renewed_at` column is in there, and they're always different in sense than they're not ever the same date even if they're both present. `created_at` is always present.

Is is possible to do it? Or am I thinking this the wrong way?

Comment: @ypercube thanks I just typed the query in without running it. its edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might work, assuming that by *not present* you mean *is NULL*:

```
select * from subscription where
coalesce ( subscription.renewed_at, subscription.created_at ) 
between '2013-10-16 00:00:00.000000' and '2013-10-16 23:59:59.999999')
```

The `coalesce()` function returns its first non-NULL argument, so if `renewed_at` is present it will be returned, otherwise `created_at` will be the result.

Alternatively, you could use this, which will work in case *not present* means something else in your table, e.g. the value `9999-01-01-00-00-00`:

```
select * from subscription where
(subscription.renewed_at 
   between '2013-10-16 00:00:00.000000' and '2013-10-16 23:59:59.999999')
or ( 
subscription.renewed_at = '9999-01-01-00-00-00' 
and 
subscription.created_at 
   between '2013-10-16 00:00:00.000000' and '2013-10-16 23:59:59.999999'
)
```